# CSS Transform Tricks

Tags: css

Two things: 
First, I am having a difficult time of the line change to five different colors when the mouse hovers over it. The the second thing, I have a triangle and a circle. Much like the two red squares at this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_2dtransforms.asp), I want to provide a 3D animation on the triangle and a 2D effect to the circle.

```
<div class="transform">
  <div class="transform-line" id="line">HOVER OVER LINE</div>
  <div onmouseover="rotateYDIV()" id="rotate3D">
    <img src="http://images3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20071127055923/uncyclopedia/images/c/c1/Penrose_triangle.png" alt="3D triangle" />
  </div>
  <div onmouseover="rotateDIV()" id="rotate2D">
    <img src="http://www.collectorsheaven.info/images/products/1168.png" alt="2D circle" />
  </div>

</div>

div.transform-line {
  font-size: .95em;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0px auto;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  /*height: 5px;*/
  padding: 2px;
  /*background-color: #FF69B4;*/
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: HotPink;
  transition: width 3s;
  /* Chrome and Safari */
  -webkit-animation-name: line;
  animation-name: line;
}

div.transform-line:hover {
  width: 600px;
  color: #000000;
}

@-webkit-keyframes W3C
/* Chrome and Safari */

{
  0% {
    background: Pink;
  }
  25% {
    background: DeepPink;
  }
  50% {
    background: #ffe0e5;
  }
  75% {
    background: HotPink;
  }
  100% {
    background: #ff9baa;
  }
}

@keyframes W3C {
  0% {
    background: Pink;
  }
  25% {
    background: DeepPink;
  }
  50% {
    background: #ffe0e5;
  }
  75% {
    background: HotPink;
  }
  100% {
    background: #ff9baa;
  }
}


/***** 2D & 3D *****/

#rotate2D,
#rotate3D {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

I have the issues in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/leosnake123/x0nqv7hk/2/).

Comment: Your fiddle is missing Javascript

Comment: May I ask why you unaccepted my answer, almost a month later?

Answer (score 0):

There's several things about transitions and transforms that you seem to be missing.

[Here's a working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cale_b/agdyge2y/1/)

Your CSS needs to be modified as follows for any of these things to work:

```
div.transform-line {
  font-size: .95em;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0px auto;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 2px;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: HotPink;
}

div.transform-line:hover {
  width: 600px;
  color: #000000;
  /* the animation name has to match the keyframes name below */
  animation: W3C 3s;
}

@keyframes W3C {
  0% {
    background: Pink;
    width: 300px;
  }
  25% {
    background: DeepPink;
  }
  50% {
    background: #ffe0e5;
  }
  75% {
    background: HotPink;
  }
  100% {
    background: #ff9baa;
    width: 600px;
  }
}


/***** circle *****/

#rotate2D {
  transition: transform 3s;
  transform-origin: 157px 157px;
}

#rotate2D:hover {
  transform: rotate(180deg);  
}

#rotate3D {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px;
  transition: transform 3s;
  transform-origin: 140px 0;
}

#rotate3D:hover {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

There's a LOT to know about transforms and keyframe animation.

W3Schools isn't the best resource for these types of things - try a few of these resources.
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax/
https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transform/
http://learn.shayhowe.com/advanced-html-css/css-transforms/

Comment: Okay, but how would the element still operate when the cursor isn't hovering over said element?

Comment: What do you mean "still operate"? What would you expect it to do / not do?

Comment: In the link (http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_2dtransforms.asp) I've provided, when you hover over one of the red boxes and take off the cursor off, the box still transform despite the cursor not being on it.

Comment: Okay, so how can you make the objects transform in place?

Comment: What do you mean "in place"?

Comment: As far as "staying" transformed, W3 Schools used JavaScript to add a class on hover rather than using the hover pseudo class.  That way they could "leave" the class in place so that the transform stays.